# activity background image from url android studio

Tags: android

Generally we set background like this

```
  android:background="@mipmap/bg"
```

but i want to make my application size as less as possible so i want to import images from a remote website 
suppose **i want to use this image as background: http://www.example.com/bg.png**

but

```
  android:background="http://www.example.com/bg.png"
```

is not working

Answer (score 1):

Use `Picasso Library` for loading the image.

add this to `build.gradle` file

```
//    picasso
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

initialize the `ImageView`,

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
Picasso.with(context).load("http://www.example.com/bg.png").into(imageView);
```

thats all !!